# How to implement a call back?

Tags: java

How do I use a callback to call computerMove() AFTER resetBoard() is completely finished? Basically I am trying to use a delay using a handler but I am having a loop in my code and I believe it is because `computerMove()` is occuring whilst the board is resetting.

Code below:

```
    @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    turnsCount++;

                    if (playerOneMove) {
                        ((Button) v).setText("X");
                        ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
                        isGameOver();
                    }

                }

                public void isGameOver() {

                    if (checkGameIsWon()) {
                        if (playerOneMove) {
                            player1Wins();
                        } else {
                            player2Wins();
                        }
                    } else if (turnsCount == 9) {
                        draw();
                    } else {
                        playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
                        if (!playerOneMove) {
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    computerMove();
                                }
                            }, random.nextInt(2000 - 1000 + 1000) + 1000);
                        }
                    }
                }

      private void computerMove() {
            String[][] field = new String[3][3];
            List<Button> emptyButtons = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                    if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                        emptyButtons.add(buttons[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }

    selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));

    selectButton.setText("O");
                    selectButton.setTextColor(playerO);
                    firstComputerMove = false;
                    turnsCount++;
                    isGameOver();

            }

                private void player1Wins() {
                    playerOnePoints++;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updatePointsText();
                    resetBoard();
                }

                private void resetBoard() {

                    final Handler handlerReset = new Handler();
                    handlerReset.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                    buttons[i][j].setText("");
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        },2000);
            } 

        private boolean checkGameIsWon() {
                String[][] field = new String[3][3];

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                            && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                            && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                            && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                            && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                        && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                        && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                        && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                        && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            private void player1Wins() {
                playerOnePoints++;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Player 1 wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updatePointsText();
                resetBoard();
            }

 private void player2Wins() {
            playerTwoPoints++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Computer wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updatePointsText();
            resetBoard();
            firstComputerMove = true;
            computerMove();
        }

        private void draw() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resetBoard();
            playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
            switchPlayerTurn();
            if (!playerOneMove){
                firstComputerMove = true;
                computerMove();
            }
        }
```

Error Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mima.tictactoe, PID: 10915
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
                      at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:163)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.player2Wins(MainActivityPlayer1.java:340)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.isGameOver(MainActivityPlayer1.java:129)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.computerMove(MainActivityPlayer1.java:283)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1.access$200(MainActivityPlayer1.java:20)
                      at com.mima.tictactoe.MainActivityPlayer1$3.run(MainActivityPlayer1.java:140)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, your question isn't very clear, but I can tell 2 things about your question:

- Your Error Trace says that `emptyButtons` in `computerMove` shouldn't be empty when calling random

- To create a callback, do something like:
<pre><code>    public Runnable runnable = null;
    public void computerMove() { /*Code*/}
    
    public void registerComputerMove() {
      runnable = () -> computerMove();`
    }
    
    public void reset() {
      //Code
      if (runnable != null)
        runnable.run();
    }</pre></code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. You are executing a `Runnable` within your `resetBoard()` method, which runs the contents of that method in a separate thread than your `computerMove()` method; this is why those two methods are running concurrently. Does your `resetBoard()` logic need to be inside of its own thread? You can probably get rid of the thread and just let that logic run normally and this would alleviate your issue, unless you are **certain** that you need to use a separate Thread here.
2. The exception you are seeing is a *side-effect* of your `computerMove()` and `resetBoard()` logic running on separate threads;  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)` is being thrown because you are passing in 0 to a random number function `emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));` on line 182. The condition `if (field[i][j].equals(""))` isn't passing, likely because your `resetBoard()` method hasn't completed by the time `computerMove()` gets called, so the value at `field[i][j]` is not yet set to `""`.
3. Formatting your code to get rid of any logic that is not related to your question, as well as fixing the indentation would help others give you some better possible solutions.

---

Perhaps a better approach is to use a `Thread` rather than a `Runnable` in your `resetBoard()` method. It gives you the ability to tap into the `wait` and `notify` functionality if you are *sure* you want to use a separate thread. [Check out how to use wait and notify with Threads here](https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/)

```
private Runnable resetBoard() {
    return new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(this){
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        buttons[i][j].setText("");
                    }
                }
                notify();
            }                
        }
    }
}

private void computerMove(Thread resetBoard) {
    resetBoard.start();

    synchronized(resetBoard){
        try{
            System.out.println("Resetting board...");
            resetBoard.wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Board is reset.");

        // ...
        // existing computerMove() logic here
        // ...
    }
}

public void draw() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // resetBoard(); -- don't call here
    playerOneMove = !playerOneMove;
    switchPlayerTurn();
    if (!playerOneMove){
        firstComputerMove = true;

        // pass the result of resetBoard (new thread) here
        computerMove(resetBoard());
    }
}
```

For future reference, it's never really a good idea to simply try to use a time delay to "wait" for the logic of another thread to continue finishing before executing some other logic. There are a variety of reasons why you'll never really know exactly how long something will take before it finishes, so you shouldn't just "guess" and use something like 2000 ms (2 seconds). Understand how Threads work in Java, and understand why and when you should use Thread lifecycle hooks, like `wait` and `notify`.

Comment: Is it ok for point number one if you can show me the two methods you mentioned just so I have a better idea visually in understanding what you mean? Sorry I have only been developing for a few months so I am still at beginner leve when it comes to terminology and understanding. thanks

Comment: Or even the last point you just made about passing resetBoard as a lambda

Comment: Yeah will deffo need help implementing it

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer and I've learned some things

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help :)